# catkin cmake error with ros

Tags: ros, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone. I am following the tutorial here to create a workspace with catkin using python3:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

When I invoke

```
catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3
```

I get this output..

```
Base path: /home/ros/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/ros/catkin_ws/src -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/ros/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ros/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/ros/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.6.9", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ros/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.6.9") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/ros/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:168 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ros/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ros/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I tried anything to find a way to fix it.. and last time, I re-installed Ubuntu OS. But it's still occurred. I'm a new to ROS. Thank you for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354833/catkin-cmake-error-with-ros/) by [hiro1117](https://answers.ros.org/users/55764/hiro1117/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2020-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure the Python 3 interpreter you want to use has the required packages installed. If you've installed ROS using `apt`, only the default, system provided interpreter will have packages such as `catkin_pkg` installed. So any other interpreter will not be able to find them.

At the very least, you'll have to install `catkin_pkg` for `/usr/bin/python3`.

Note this is also mentioned by the page you link:

[image: install Python pkgs yourself]

If that Python interpreter was installed using `apt`, you should use the binary packages for `catkin_pkg` available through the ROS repositories as well. Provided you have those configured correctly already (because you've installed ROS already fi), you should run

```
sudo apt install python3-catkin-pkg
```

If you installed the Python 3 interpreter by building it from source, it's possible that even with the `.deb` package installed, `catkin_pkg` will not be picked up by your Python-from-source. In that case, you'll most likely have to make use of `pip` to install it for that interpreter. `pip3 install catkin_pkg` should install it in this case.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hiro1117](https://answers.ros.org/users/55764/hiro1117/) on 2020-06-13**:
Thank you very much for your comment and help!!
I just ran the code and installed catkin_pkg and it ran perfect!!
Thank you so much!!

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-06-15**:
On Ubuntu / Debian you shouldn't install Python packages with `pip` if there is an equivalent `.deb`. Simply because any new releases available from `.deb` won't be visible on your system since the `pip` package (which don't get updated automatically) will take precedence. You should `pip3 uninstall catkin_pkg` again and `apt install python3-catkin-pkg-modules` instead (the `-module` packages for Python 2 and 3 are side-by-side installable.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-15**:
Python `3.6.9` does not appear to be a version of Python 3 on Ubuntu provided by Canonical (or at least: I cannot find it listed here: [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python/python3). Not in updates, nor in Eoan or newer).

Wouldn't the `apt` package only work for the system packaged version of Python 3?

That's why I suggested using `pip3` in this case.

---

Edit: ah, it's the [python3.6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3.6) package on Bionic.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-15**:
I've just updated my answer.

`python3.6` does have its own directory under /usr/lib`, but also loads the packages from` /usr/lib/python3`. That's the reason this can work with the` .deb`.